# Angular2 change node_modules path

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 project and I want to move my node_modules folder to a different location.

Say for example my project is in **C:\Users\Me\MyAngularProject** and i want my modules to be in **C:\node_modules** (not the global one by the way).

Where can I set this path in the configuration files of my project ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders `It is strongly encouraged to place dependencies in the local node_modules folder. These will be loaded faster, and more reliably.`

Comment: Looks like the NODE_PATH is declared globally. There is no solution to put it in one of the .json configuration file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no simple configuration setting. Having node_modules outside the current project is considered bad practice. Although there is a number of use cases for it.

You can use a juncture on Windows

```
mklink /j node_modules C:\node_modules
```

or a symlink on Linux

```
ln -s ~/shared_node_modules node_modules
```

After you have done this, you need to add `--preserve-symlinks` to `ng build` and `ng serve` in order to prevent typescript warnings and include style sheets.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7081) to add `--preserve-symlinks` to `ng test`. It seems to work without but there is a huge number of annoying warnings at the moment.

Comment: Perfect answer. Stackoverflow should allow users to submit an answer to appear in answer example for new users.

Comment: You saved my life, tks :)